# Rails console returning binary field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, binary, rails-console

I have a binary field called extra_data. When I output this field within the pry-console in development, I get:

```
t.extra_data
=> "\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\vdescription\x00\x00\x000Child Sponsorship Fund:  Haiti:  Cyvadier:  Adne\x00\x00\x00\vcard_number\x00\x00\x00\bXXXX6006\x00\x00\x00\x0Fexpiration_date\x00\x00\x00\x04XXXX\x00\x00\x00\x06method\x00\x00\x00\x01M"
```

On production, which does not use pry-console of course, it outputs from the normal rails console:

```
t.extra_data
=> "x000000040000000b6465736372697074696f6e000000304368696c642053706f6e736f72736869702046756e643a202048616974693a202043797661646965723a202041646e650000000b636172645f6e756d6265720000000858585858363030360000000f65787069726174696f6e5f646174650000000458585858000000066d6574686f64000000014d"
```

I am a bit baffled what I need to do so in production it will display as it does within development. Does anyone have an idea?

**Update**

After looking into this some more, it appear it has nothing to do pry console vs rails normal console. Just for some reason when I start up the console on my production environment it displays the field differently than on my development.

Comment: what is production using to display the value then?

Comment: I am using rails console to output that. I think pry is doing something to the extra_data binary field that I need to replicate.